# Wrapping input placeholder text not working in Firefox

Tags: html, css, firefox, input

I am trying to get my placeholder text to wrap to the next line on an input field. I found examples on how to do this and it's working in Chrome but not Firefox.

This is the Stack Overflow question I took my code from:

[Placeholder auto wrap inside a input field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39761030/placeholder-auto-wrap-inside-a-input-field)

That works for Chrome but not Firefox. I know my pseudo element is working because when I do something else obvious (i.e. color: red), that does change the input text. I am looking for help on the wrap stylings specifically.

```
::-moz-placeholder {
    white-space:pre-line;  
    position:relative;
    top:-7px;
}
```

(This doesn't work in FF)

```
::-webkit-input-placeholder {
    white-space:pre-line;  
    position:relative;
    top:-7px;
}
```

(This does work in Chrome)

I am looking to get the input placeholder to wrap down to the next line and not get cut off.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know Mozilla Firefox removed the ability to wrap the placeholder. The placeholder element is extremely tricky and technically not that well supported.

A solutions can be to remove placeholders entirely and rely on another option. Here's an [article](https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2018/06/placeholder-attribute/) about (not) using the placeholder and its alternatives from Smashing Magazine.